# Why does calling this Python method not return anything?

Tags: python

```
class Solution:
    def minDepth(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> int:
        if not root:
            return 0
        
        def DFS(root, depth):
            if (not root.left) and (not root.right):
                return depth
            if root.left:
                DFS(root.left, depth + 1)
            if root.right:
                DFS(root.right, depth + 1)
        
        DFS(root, 1)
```

Does anyone know why this returns None? How can I create a DFS helper function and return the value depth?

Comment: You have to have `return` statements in *all branches the code can take*.  Only one of two possibilities actually returns anything in `minDepth()`, and one of three possibilities in `DFS()`.  In all of the cases where you call `DFS()`, its return value (if it even has one) gets thrown away.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom your recursive function returns depth, but all the other functions do not take the first path and return nothing,  You need return statements on all your paths